# Focus Screenshot on the Flash Content of a Webpage

Tags: screenshot, screen-capture

I want to know if there's a way to take a screenshot of only the flash content of a website? I'm making a review of a certain game that runs on flash but it's uncomfortable to have to have to size the screenshot tool I'm using to the size of the flash content every time.

Comment: Chances are, there's also a flash ad displayed next to the game. It'd probably easier to find a screenshot tool that does configurable fixed-location screenshots. Don't move the browser window, or scroll, and you should be able to just get the relevant part of the screen every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Windows, [Greenshot](http://www.getgreenshot.org) has a "Capture last region" option, so you can take the first screenshot choosing the region, then use a hotkey for each additional screenshot that will capture the same region.

Comment: Any tips for mac users?

Comment: @ShedoSurashu: None that I have first-hand experience with. Unless someone else answers, you should start testing out the various screenshot utilities that exist. Just use Google to find them. If you find one, please post it as an answer so the community can benefit from what you learned!